# Writing large text file with javascript, not working with firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am trying to write a large csv file within javascript and download it.  The code below works in chrome, but won't export more than ~1200 characters with firefox. When I look at the string it has everything in it, it just won't download. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
var errorFile = 'Long text, 123456789,  123456789, 123456789, 123456789, 123456789,....'
link.download = 'Test_errors.csv';
link.href = 'data:application/octet-stream,' + errorFile;
//link.href = 'data:application/text/plain,' + errorFile;  tried this but didn't work either.

document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();

// Cleanup the DOM
 document.body.removeChild(link);
link = null;
```

Comment: Can you check your `about:config` and see if *download scanning* is turned off. If not, turn it off and try again.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues found the answer.  Instead of just writing it out, we changed it to a Blob object and then wrote it out.

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
var errorFile = 'Long text, 123456789,  123456789, 123456789, 123456789, 123456789,....'
link.download = 'Test_errors.csv';

var blob = new Blob([errorFile], {
     "type": "application/text/html;"
});
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();

// Cleanup the DOM
document.body.removeChild(link);
link = null;
```